# Opencart: Two Different types of invoices

Tags: php, opencart

I have installed an extension which converts the standard order_invoice.tpl to pdf.

This extension creates one more button "Download pdf invoice".

Now there are two buttons. One is opencart default "PRINT INVOICE" and second is "DOWNLOAD PDF INVOICE". As of now they both are pointing to order_invoice.tpl.

Can I make this functionality as below:

1. "PRINT INVOICE": points to new order_invoice1.tpl
2. "DOWNLOAD PDF INVOICE" points to default order_invoice.tpl

I have tried creating another ORDER_INVOICE1.TPL in admin\view\template\sale

And I had also updated order.php (admin\controller\sale) at bottom end as below:

```
                    }
        }

        $this->template = 'sale/order_invoice.tpl';
        $this->template = 'sale/order_invoice1.tpl';


        $this->response->setOutput($this->render());
    }
}
?>
```

Could someone please assist me if I am missing something as its not working out.
This will help customise templates based on the type of orders and customer residing in different locations.

Link to extension : http://www.opencart.com/index.php?route=extension/extension/info&extension_id=6331

Comment: By doing that you overwrite the first template with the second one. I do not know how the extension works but I guess there should be a new action for the PDF download - you should change the template only for that PDF download action.

Comment: That extension is using the order_invoice.tpl to convert the invoice into pdf...is there a way to achieve above...i have no problems even if i need to point "DOWNLOAD PDF INVOICE" points to new order_invoice1.tpl and "PRINT INVOICE": points to default order_invoice.tpl and vice versa..Thanks for your help..

Comment: On that place, where the extension uses the template, just rename the template to the desired one. Or if you cannot achieve that, then keep the `order_invoice.tpl` to be used by PDF download and create a new `order_invoice1.tpl` that will be used for HTML invoice... Or maybe I do not get where is the problem...

Comment: I did that. the download pdf button disappears after doing this.

Comment: @DavKan you must show some code from that extension to let us know how that extension is using `order_invoice.tpl` or its doing in some another way. otherwise we will be just shooting in the dark

Comment: @ChetanPaliwal: I tried putting code in original post..but it was giving some formatting error. Please find below the extension link: http://www.opencart.com/index.php?route=extension/extension/info&extension_id=6331   ..It has vqmod xml in it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the link given by you to the [extension](http://www.opencart.com/index.php?route=extension/extension/info&extension_id=6331)

there is a code in `invoice-to-pdf-1.21.154.xml`

```
if ($pdf){
    $this->response->setOutput(pdf($this->render(),$this->data['orders']));
}else{
    $this->response->setOutput($this->render());
}
```

replace it with

```
if ($pdf){
    $this->template = 'sale/order_invoice_for_pdf.tpl';
    $this->response->setOutput(pdf($this->render(),$this->data['orders']));
}else{
    $this->template = 'sale/order_invoice.tpl';
    $this->response->setOutput($this->render());
}
```

now you can have two separate tpl `order_invoice_for_pdf.tpl` and `order_invoice.tpl` for different purposes

Comment: It worked like charm. But giving a very small problem. It is adding one extra blank page in every pdf for order_invoice_for_pdf.tpl when i download pdf. Any help will be highly appreciated..

Comment: Previously it was working fine though..something more to be added in above code to get rid of this..??

Comment: @DavKan first use exact same content of original tpl in new tpl, if in that case it does not create a extra page then you can be sure you are doing something in content of your new tpl which is causing this extra page

Comment: I tried with same content in both. Still its showing an extra page in pdf.. :-(.. could u please advice...thanks

Comment: I did some changes. i changed <div style="page-break-after: always;"> to <div style="page-break-after: auto;">....This resolves the issue...could u let me know if this is right..Thanks

Comment: @DavKan yes its ok there is no problem with that